# SolidJS: Is there a way to pass in an object to the first param of `createResource`

Tags: solid-js

Is there a way to pass in an object to the first param of `createResource`? For example: I am trying the following and it is not working:

`const [val] = createResource(props, req);`

I have also tried a few other things including the following:

`const [val] = createResource(signal(), req);`

`const [val] = createResource(["foo","bar"], req);`

`const [val] = createResource(merged, req);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the source argument of `createResource` to be reactive, you need to pass a function that is reading from a signal. Then the `createResource` will be able to track it and refetch when it changes.

```js
const [data] = createResource(() => ({ ...props }), fetcher);
```

Here I'm destructuring props object to read all of its properties within the tracking scope of the source function.

[Playground demo](https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-73930518&version=1.4.1)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a longer explanation for someone like whose unable to grasp the answer in the first go:

You can define two signals:

```
  const [state1, setState1] = createSignal("");
  const [state2, setState2] = createSignal("");
```

You need to create a function that derives the state from those signals:

```
  const derivedState = () => {
    console.log('func called')
    return {value1: state1(), value2: state2()}
  }
```

You can then use it with your fetcher in createResource:

```
  const [data] = createResource(derivedState, fetcherFunction);
```

This is what an example signature for the fetcher looks like:

```
async function fetcherFunction(derivedState: {
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
}) {
  ...
```

Comment: I came back and saw this a few months after you posted - this was very helpful. Thank you!